# How to use ElementName binding from resource?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've added a MenuFlyout to a button in ItemsControl.ItemTemplate. Also I was able to bind current item as CommandParameter. 
Now I want to bind Command to a MenuFlyoutItem. 
In codebehind :

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
```

So if i bind to LayoutRoot I will actually bind to my current UserControl. But the following binding is not working:

```
Command="{Binding ActivateProfileCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
```

It gives me not errors in Output but it's not working. 
Here's the full example:

```
<controls:HeaderDecorator x:Uid="AccountsHeader" Text="Accounts" x:Name="LayoutRoot" Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:HeaderDecorator.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Key="AccountMenuFlyout">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Activate" Name="Activate" 
                        Command="{Binding ActivateProfileCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </controls:HeaderDecorator.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Settings.Profiles}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding}"  FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource AccountMenuFlyout}" >
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ic:ShowFlyoutBehavior />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</controls:HeaderDecorator>
```

Seems the problem is i'm trying to use shared object in Resources. Can I do it? And why not?

Comment: Where did you define ActivateProfileCommand?

Comment: ActivateProfileCommand is in UserControl. DataContext of LayoutRoot set to this UserControl. Actually I see it should be "{Binding DataContext.ActivateProfileCommand..." but that doesn't work also.

Comment: Try changing the ElementName to UserControl which the command is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing here is the **MenuFlyoutItem** is no longer in the *datacontext* you perhaps think it is. I'll try and explain this as best I can as a few I know who work with xaml have come across this and hit their heads off walls for days about it. It's also known to not show errors in your particular scenario; further increasing confusion.

In a nutshell. When the **MenuFlyout** is added inside the **ItemTemplate** of each item in your collection, it does not have access to the *datacontext* you perhaps think it does. In this case, the *datacontext* that the control now resides is actually the individual item within the collection it is sitting in.

There is however a solution to this. I have something similar to yourself. An **ItemsControl** which has it's **ItemsTemplate** defined that includes a **UIElement** who's **FlyoutBase** AP references a **MenuFlyout** defined in a resource dictionary.

The xaml is pretty much the same except I don't need the *ElementName* in the binding.

However, I have now turned my attention to the type that the collection holds. I have code that looks something like this.

```
public class AnItemToList
{
   public AnItemToList(Action commandDel)
   {
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand(commandDel);
   }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public RelayCommand TestCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the command is being defined in the item itself and that I'm passing the method that the command will execute via the constructor.

All I have to do for the command binding on the **MenuFlyoutItem** is

```
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Activate"
                Name="Activate"
                Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

I don't have a command param set here as I just quickly put together a basic template Windows Phone app and the pre-packed ICommand implementation doesn't have a delegate set to take the param.

If you now stick a break point in the method the command is calling, you'll see it will be called from any of the **MenuFlyoutItem**'s bound to the command that references it.

Bare in mind that this isn't the only way of solving this problem; but it is one I use myself on occasion. For example, in WPF XAML you can make use of *RelativeSource* to go looking for the command on a parent control's *datacontext*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The only problem with this is that (usually i think) one would want a command inside some aggregate object. Not inside "Item" itself. Cause how you can, for example, delete item without knowing collection? I've used another way to workaround this. I created a sample dependency object called "Pair". In this "Pair" I put Item and object with commands. Now I can easily bind Command and CommandParameter in MenuFlyout resource and it can be completely different objects.

Comment: @norekhov And why can't the "aggregate object" be your "Item"? I think you don't have to know the item - the collection already does (and from the collection you do too).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general "Pair" object:

```
public class Pair : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("First",
        typeof(object), typeof(Pair), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Second",
        typeof(object), typeof(Pair), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object First
    {
        get { return GetValue(FirstProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Second
    {
        get { return GetValue(SecondProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In ItemTemplate i put something like this:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <viewModel:Pair x:Key="Tuple" First="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" 
                                                           Second="{Binding}" />
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Second.ProfileName}" 
                                     DataContext="{StaticResource Tuple}"
                                     FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource AccountMenuFlyout}" 
                        </HyperlinkButton>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Now I can easily reference Tuple elements from my Resource like this:

```
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Activate" Name="Activate" 
                        Command="{Binding First.ActivateProfileCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Second}" />
```

Comment: I defiantly agree that yes it's better to contain the commands in some viewmodel. For the concern about accessing the collection. This is the reason I was passing the method to the item, rather than contain the method within the item class itself. This way the method can access the collection. When when deleting gc does occur without problems.

I'm happy you solved your problem.